# Identify a component in a picture of a motor controller

Tags: identification, components, controller

I have the picture below of an electronic component I want to identify and get the meaning of the code marked on it. There are two of them pointed with arrows. The code on the visible one is J1K.

The controller is Navitas TPM400-48.

[image]

Comment: silkscreen label indicates that each one may be a zener diode

Comment: https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/409583/CENTRAL/CMOZ16V.html

Comment: You may want to try cleaning ZD13 with alcohol (isopropyl alcohol) to see if any more of the marking can be read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"J1" appears to be a common marking for an MMSZ5246 16V zener diode in a SOD-123 package:

- [Diodes Inc](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/diodes-incorporated/MMSZ5246B-7-F/717793)
- [Vishay](https://www.vishay.com/docs/85774/mmsz5225.pdf)
- [Panjit](https://www.panjit.com.tw/en/Product/downloadPDF/MMSZ5246A)

The "K" is probably a date code, but without knowing the manufacturer it would be difficult to decode - although for finding a replacement it wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

From silkscreen marking, it looks like it is a Zener diode to limit the voltage. You'll need to tell us which specific motor driver you are using (part number or a link.)

Comment: Hi Noman, it is a TPM400-48 controller from Navitas. I just added this information

Comment: Do you know how to interpret the code on it?